# Data structure for represent Regex Java

Tags: java

I am trying to represent a Regex with a data structure in Java.

I create a class like this to represent the single character:

```
class RegexElement {
     String elem;
     int min;
     int max;
     boolean isOptional;
}
```

In this way I can represent for example a regex like this: `\w{4,5}`. At the first I was thinking to create a List of RegexElement, but the problem is with the iterator of block of RegexElement (in this way I can represent only for the single character, not a block like `(\w\s)+`).

So I was thinking to create an abstract class called `Element`, and two subclass: one `RegexElement` and the other `IteratorBlockElement`. The first represent a single character like before, the second a block of character iterated. In this way, the instance variable of `IteratorBlockElement` is a List of Element, because could happen two nested iterator, like: `(\w(\d\w)+)+`.

If I manage this regex with the domain described, I will have a List of Element with one object, an `IteratorBlockElement`, that is composed by a `RegexElement` and by another `IteratorBlockElement`, that is composed by two `RegexElement`.

I am not so sure that is correct, create a subclass that has an instance variable his superclass, so it could have instance of itself. Probably there is a smarter solution, a pattern for this special case. Thanks!

Comment: Lets step back and ask: why do want to do this? In other words: proper design depends on your intended use case to a certain degree. But please understand that your question is borderline close to being too broad or going into the "opinion based answer" direction.

Comment: @GhostCat. And it's on the wrong side of that border, based on my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

It is perfectly OK and the natural way to have an element containing an element. This is done for example to represent expressions like `3 + 4*5`.

```
class BinaryExpr extends Expr {
    Expr left;
    BinaryOp op;
    Expr right;
}
```

To see how many data types are necessary for the full-blown Java regular expressions, read the source code of `java.util.Pattern`.